# angulajs ng-class not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

am trying to apply class dynamically using ng-class within an ng-repeat but class definations(rules) is not taking effect eventhough the class name is applied to the html. here is the codes:

```
The controller:

controller('MessagesCtrl', ['MessageService', '$routeParams', 'socket', function (MessageService, $routeParams, socket) {
  var self = this
  self.messages = [
    {msg: 'First messaging service', username: 'Jane Doe', dpurl: 'mode.jpg', from: 'me'},
   {msg: 'another messaging service', username: 'John Doe', dpurl: 'model2.jpg', from: 'you'},
   {msg: ' messaging', username: 'John Doe', dpurl: 'model2.jpg', from: 'me'}
  ]

}])
```

The html:

```
  <div class="chatcontainer" >
      <div ng-repeat="message in msgCtrl.messages" class="d-flex msgcontainer" ng-class="message.from?'me':'you'"><span class="badge badge-primary mr-auto msg">{{message.msg}}</span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
ng-class={'me':message.from, 'you':!message.from}
```

Comment: i did just that but still getting same result:<div ng-repeat="message in msgCtrl.messages" class="d-flex msgcontainer" ng-class={message.from?'me':'you'}><span class="badge badge-primary msg" ng-class={'mr-auto':message.from, 'mr-auto':!message.from}>{{message.msg}}</span></div>

Answer (score 2):

use 
ng-class="(message.from) ? 'me' : 'you'"

Or

ng-class="message.from"

OR

ng-class={'me':(message.from==='me'), 'you':(message.from!=='me')}

Comment: The thing is that angular is actually applying the class name when i inspect the html element but the class definition associated with that name is not takin  in my css file is not taking effect

Answer (score 1):

I tried out the same, hope this will help you.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages" class="d-flex msgcontainer" ng-class="{'me':message.from==='me', 'you':message.from==='you'}">
<span class="badge badge-primary msg" ng-class="{'mr-auto':message.from==='me', 'mr-auto1':message.from==='you'}">{{message.msg}}</span>
```

and classes used,

```
.me {
    color: red;
}
.you {
    color: blue;
}
.mr-auto {
    font-size : 14px;
}
.mr-auto1 {
    font-size : 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the value, as your object don't have a boolean value.

```
<div class="chatcontainer" >
      <div ng-repeat="message in msgCtrl.messages" class="d-flex msgcontainer" ng-class="message.from=='me' ?'me':'you'"><span class="badge badge-primary mr-auto msg">{{message.msg}}</span>
</div
```

[Many-ways-to-use-ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Answer (score 0):

actually it was a logic error on my own part, all the syntax suggested above works when i rewrite my logic as:
  {{message.msg}}